# Caret (^) does not register immediately. Java key listener

Tags: java, keyevent

I am currently building a calculator in Java and have started implementing
a key listener. It works very well, but when I try to type the caret symbol (^) it doesn't register immediately. You have to press another key first to make it appear.

I guess the reason for this is that it uses the same behavior as when you try to type a caret
in a regular text document. But is there any way to come around this behavior?

If it helps, here is my code to handle the KeyEvents:

```
@Override
public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {
    String key = ke.getCharacter();

    if (key.matches("[0-9*/+-=.()^%]")) {
        controller.getButton(key).fire();
    }
}
```

EDIT: Found a workaround. The problem as Eli Sadoff mentioned is that my caret is a dead key on my keyboard. Since my binding for the caret is " shift+¨ ", I was able to solve it like this:

```
@Override
public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {
    String key = ke.getCharacter();

    if (ke.isShiftDown() && ke.getCode() == KeyCode.DEAD_DIAERESIS) {
        controller.getButton("^").fire();
    }

    else if (key.matches("[0-9*/+-=.()%]")) {
        controller.getButton(key).fire();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have this same problem with `+`, `(`, `)`, and `%` by chance?

Comment: No, neither of them.

Comment: Is your caret key a dead key on your computer? (Meaning typing `^` and then `e` would produce `ê`)

Comment: Yes, seems like it... So the problem lies at my end?

Comment: Kind of. Try changing to a different input language. The standard US English keyboard doesn't have `^` as a dead key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the input keyboard layout you are using on your computer treats <kbd>^</kbd> as a dead key, as it is a combining diacritic. The way to fix this would be to change your input keyboard layout to a keyboard that does not treat <kbd>^</kbd> as a combining diacritic. This can be tested by typing <kbd>^</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> and seeing if it results in `ê` or `^e`.

Comment: Posted my workaround to the problem as an edit to the question.